# Unable to set " Force SPDY Over SSL " to false in chrome

Tags: http, ssl, spdy

I am new to SPDY and have worked on HTTP prior to this. I know we can see the details of SPDY on chrome using `chrome://net-internals/#events&q=type:SPDY_SESSION%20is:active URL`.
For running some test cases, I was trying to disable the option to force SSL over SPDY.

ie,

```
SPDY Enabled: true
Use Alternate Protocol: true
Force SPDY Always: false
Force SPDY Over SSL: true
Next Protocols: http/1.1,spdy/2,spdy/3
```

Want to change " `Force SPDY Over SSL` " to false.
However when I start up chrome from command line with  `--use-spdy=no-ssl` argument, it still shows " `Force SPDY Over SSL`" as true.

Kindly guide me where I am actually going wrong.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

You asked this question a long time ago so I am hoping you have it figured out. In case not, I am using Version 30.0.1599.101 m of Chrome on Windows and using the following command line works:

```
chrome --use-spdy=no-ssl
```

Don't forget to disable SSL on your server as well. For Apache instructions to disable SSL on Apache click [here](http://code.google.com/p/mod-spdy/wiki/ConfigOptions).